# AWS - How to change the cloudwatchclient config service version in AWSSDK for .NET

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to get CPU percentage of a particular amazon EC2 instance using CloudWatch

I am facing this error when executing the code (see below)

> The requested version (2010-08-01) of service AmazonEC2 does not exist"

I could not change the ServiceVersion in AmazonCloudWatchClient because it has `Read Only property`

The default set is `2010-08-01`

I need to change the ServiceVersion to `2014-10-01`

Please find the configuration below

[image: Error Image]

And the config in text here

```
  var client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(clientkey,secretkey,new     AmazonCloudWatchConfig{ServiceURL="url"})
  var dimension = new Dimension
        {
            Name = "instanceName",
            Value = "instanceID"
        };
  var request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest
        {
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { dimension },
            EndTime = DateTime.Today,
            MetricName = "CPUUtilization",
            Namespace = "AWS/EC2",
            // Get statistics by day.
            Period = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds,
            // Get statistics for the past month.
            StartTime = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30)),
            Statistics = new List<string>() { "Minimum" },
            Unit = StandardUnit.Percent              
        };

  var response = client.GetMetricStatistics(request);

        if (response.Datapoints.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var point in response.Datapoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(point.Timestamp.ToShortDateString() +
                  " " + point.Minimum + "%");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you think you'd need to change the date ?

The property has indeed no setter (see [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/CloudWatch/Generated/AmazonCloudWatchConfig.cs#L61)) so you'll not be able to defined a config with such property.

I understand you dont want to reveal your information but what do you have under

```
  var dimension = new Dimension
        {
            Name = "instanceName",
            Value = "instanceID"
        };
```

The Name should be `InstanceName` and if you use you instance id as you indicate in the Value it should be `InstanceId` something like

```
  var dimension = new Dimension
        {
            Name = "InstanceId"
            Value = "i-54cfb999"
        };
```

Comment: override is not happening for config service version. again am getting same error

Comment: yes because in override there's no set method but weird, using the right Name parameter with correct associated value should work

Comment: Created partial class and configured the version AmazonCloudWatchConfig Config = new AmazonCloudWatchConfig();
      Config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
       var client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient("xxxxx", "xxxx", Config); this also not worked getting error "cannot convert amazon. cloudwatch.amazoncloudwatchconfig to amazon.regionendpoint"